# Would it be possible to speed up Android Emulator by removing unnecessary apps?

Tags: android-emulator

I am using Android SDK 1.6 and developing some simple apps. It seems everytime Android Emulator loads every default apps, like message music browser etc... I guess this cause the booting process slow (takes 1 minute overhead for me to test the code every time).

Would it be possible to take these apps out and just have my apps on the emulator? My purpose is to have a faster boot up time on emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
emulator -help
```

there are a few things you can disable.

Why you would want to disable stuff instead of having a more accurate representation of how it will actually behave on the real device, I don't know.