# how can I speed up communication between editor and android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

every time I click on "Run" from eclipse, the application takes a long time to start up and then the emulator. This one takes a long time. Is there a way to speed up this?
Thx

Comment: Buy a faster computer.

Comment: See more:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661981/would-it-be-possible-to-speed-up-android-emulator-by-removing-unnecessary-apps?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893423/how-to-simulate-speed-on-android-emulator?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975469/speed-up-android-emulator?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722962/how-to-set-up-android-emulator-for-a-specific-android-device?rq=1

Comment: This might sound obvious and you probably know that, but you don't need tu close the emulator every time. Leave it running in the background. Also enable hardware acceleration. You can read more on hardware acceleration here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Comment: I'd reccomend buying a device and testing it on that. Might not be the cheapest solution but it's the fastest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i should do some more research before you ask a quistion,

but the answer is: you can make a snap shot of youre emulator.

you can do this by going to **Window- -> AVD manager --> then select your AVD --> press Edit --> enable snap shot --> press start --> select: Save to snapshot and launch from snapshot**

hope this works for you, but next time do your homework first before asking something

Comment: It was just what I wanted! Awesome!